# Sitecore Security section creating 2 spaces via tds(yml) deployment

Tags: sitecore-client, tds

Deploying TDS(yml serialization) via Azure Devops, sitecore is creating 2 spaces (denoted in red) in the security section.

[image]

This is breaking the permissions on Workflow. Any thoughts on this?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am also seeing the same issue in Sitecore 10.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually we found the issue, the issue is with the TDS version(6.0.0.14), which is adding that space, after upgrading it to 6.0.0.18, this space issue is now resolved.
This is in sitecore version 9.3